# Value {} for parameter ReceiptHandle is invalid. Reason: The receipt handle has expired

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-sqs

I have a FIFO queue in SQS, where I keep a JSON with some information to be read and processed by a service in Spring Boot.

I have verified that the queue is showing an error message [The title of the issue] and is not processing some messages.

Follow my code:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "document_analysis.fifo")

public void documentAnalysis(@payload String document) throws Exception {
     ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
     DocumentAnalysisDTO documentDTO = objectMapper.readValue(document, DocumentAnalysisDTO.class);
     this.clientService.prepareCustomerDocument(documentDTO);

 }
```

Comment: Is the error message exactly that? If so, then you are not passing the receipt handle of the message when attempting to delete it.

Comment: Sorry for the question, but what would that be? Could you pass me the documentation link where you have it? If possible a code example for this deletion.

Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-general-identifiers.html describes receipt handles. I am unfamiliar with Spring Boot, so I can't help you with the code.

Comment: Is the message not automatically deleted after it is read from the queue? In addition I realized that the messages are taking too long to read (I only have 2 in line and have been about 20 minutes and have not been read). I don't know if it's any configuration in Spring Boot or SQS. I accept some complete example in any language.

Comment: No, you have to manually delete it yourself using the receipt handle. This is by design to allow for automatic retries: if for some reason you can't process the message, SQS will redeliver it to you after its visibility timeout expires.